What type of amplifier circuit do I need to drive a piezoelectric ultrasound transducer?
I would like to drive the following piezoelectric transducers at 200 V or their maximum voltage (60-1000 V):
https://www.manorshi.com/16mm-Dog-Repellent-Ultrasonic-Transducer-25khz-Detect-Sensor-pd40917866.html
https://www.manorshi.com/10mm-40kHz-Ultrasonic-Sensor-for-Measuring-Distance-pd40248866.html
https://www.manorshi.com/60khz-Waterproof-Transmitter-And-Receiver-Ultrasonic-Sensors-pd49054376.html
https://www.manorshi.com/100KHz-High-Frequency-Ultrasonic-Sensor-Transducer-pd48869166.html
This is for a pulse echo application and the square waves need to be run for a fraction of a second. Would these IC amplifiers running with an Arduino square wave be adequate?
https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/analog-devices-inc/ADHV4702-1BCPZ/9849820
https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/analog-devices-inc/ADHV4702-1BCPZ-R7/9921413
What type of circuit would you recommend for running them between 40 and 100 kHz?
For about 20 Vpp at 40 kHz, an op amp is also used:
https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8094247

While those amplifiers might drive a load to 200V p-p, they may overheat at 100% duty, or more likely not supply enough current to a transducer. A transistor driver with inductor/transformer would be simpler & cheaper & cooler.

Thank you for the prompt suggestion, I have seen that design as well (Fig. 4 in https://www.mdpi.com/1424-8220/16/6/867), but can a transformer work at those frequencies? Do you have another example of those circuits? Also, I only need to run this for a fraction of a second for a pulse echo application.

Does the answer about dedicated Piezo drivers help? This is only a comment as haven't checked the supported frequency range.

Since transducer data sheets don't give many details of equivalent motional reactances and motional resistance, exact circuit values are not possible.
Here's an idea for a very simple driver that uses a fairly low DC supply to generate a higher AC voltage across a 40 kHz ultrasonic transducer. It would have to be scaled for a different-frequency transducer.
These kind of transducers often require quite a few cycles to build up AC amplitude from zero. After pulses have finished, amplitude rings-down slowly to zero as well.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
You should verify that transducers don't complain about having a DC voltage constantly applied (in this case 12V). The square wave from microcontroller should idle at 0V and have 50% duty cycle.
Most piezo transducers have a significant parallel capacitance. For a 40 kHz transducer that I have, capacitance was measured at 1.3nf. In this case, C1 should be reduced by that amount, to 7.7nf.

You need to list specifications of what you are trying to accomplish.
What is the purpose of your device?
What is the duty cycle? Is it continuous or pulse?
What sort of fidelity do you need? Is square wave drive OK?
Is modulation required?
You need to know the complex impedance of the transducers. The specifications given in the links don't mention impedance, hence, you'll need to contact the manufacturer or buy samples and measure the impedance. From the size of these parts, it's probably safe to say they the impedance is on the higher side which makes driving them easier.
The opamps you list can handle a 20 mA output current. Since you don't know the impedance of the transducer, it unknown if these opamps are suitable. There are other manufacturers that make high-voltage opamps with higher current ratings.
If you can live with driving the transducer with a rectangular waveform use an H-bridge power amplifier with a transformer using a ferrite core. This sort of topology is good in to the low MHz frequency ranges without special parts and is useful in low power (under 1 watt) to tens of kilowatts applications. However, it does take design knowledge to create such circuitry and a lesson in transformer design. Transformer design above 1 kHz is not intuitive.
You can provide a series tuning element to cancel out the reactive portion of the impedance. This provides a real impedance to the power amplifier at the driving frequency (not so at the harmonics) and helps to boost the amplitude at the resonant frequency.
If you need a transmit/receive (T/R) switch, an H-bridge topology is easy to add a T/R switch as described in this post.
